# Cannot find a setter for that accepts parameter type 'kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow' DataBinding Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-stateflow

I'm using data-binding to handle MutableStateFlow in my ViewModel

```
  private val _searchSkeleton = MutableStateFlow(View.GONE)
  val searchSkeletonVis = _searchSkeleton
```

Here's my usage in the XML file

```
  app:viewVisibility="@{viewModel.searchSkeletonVis}"
```

And this is my BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("app:viewVisibility")
fun bindViewVisibility(
    @NonNull view: View,
    @NonNull visibility: Int,
) {
    view.visibility = visibility
}
```

and it gives me this error

> Cannot find a setter for  that accepts parameter type 'kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow'

But when I use LiveData it's working fine!

Comment: What version of Studio / Android Gradle Plugin are you using? `StateFlow` is only supported in version `7.0.0-alpha04` or higher as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#stateflow).

Comment: but the latest version of the plugin is v6.8 you can see it here https://gradle.org/releases/

Comment: The Android Gradle Plugin is different from Gradle itself.

Comment: Yes, I check it but you have to update the Android Studio version also to a beta version, thanks

Comment: So..you haven't upgraded to the minimum version of the Android Gradle Plugin that supports `StateFlow`? How do you expect it to work then?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Actually, I will not use it until it becomes the next stable version of Android Studio be available, I reviewed my mind when I saw that :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stateflow is only supported in Android Gradle Plugin version 7.0.0-alpha04 or higher as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#stateflow).